# Unable to insert serialized XML Array to Database (MySQLi)

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to integrate a PHP plugin with my web app, but I am stuck with storing the values that I receive from an XML file to a table in my database.

This is what I have so far, but when I run the PHP script it does not save to the database. I have created a table in my database with one column (type=text, name=test)

```
    global $mysqli;

    $str = serialize($Items);
    printF($str);
    $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO nepremicnine (test) VALUES ('$str');");
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working.

Comment: You do have an extra semicolon toward the end of your result statement. Logs would show this. `('$str');");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$Items` probably contains some strings with single quotes, and this is causing a syntax error when you substitute it into the `INSERT` query. Use a prepared statement to avoid problems with special characters.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO nepremicnine (test) VALUES (?);");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $str);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: This was correct, sorry for the late approval, but your solution helped me out :)